# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is inserting a new Record

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video_video_sprout` (
  `video_id` int(6) default NULL,
  `sprout_video_id` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `is_video_type` tinyint(1) default NULL ,
  `someval` varchar(25) default NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO `video_video_sprout` (`video_id`, `sprout_video_id`, `is_video_type`,someval) VALUES(62, '4c9ad9b71c1fe2c6c4', 1,'empty');


INSERT INTO video_video_sprout (video_id,sprout_video_id,is_video_type)
 VALUES(62, '4c9ad9b71c1fe2c6c4', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
someval="UpdatedValue" ;
```

Incase the row already exists , i want to update that row , or else i need to insert that row

I was trying it this way

```
 INSERT INTO video_video_sprout 
            (video_id,sprout_video_id,is_video_type)
        VALUES
            (62, '4c9ad9b71c1fe2c6c4', 1) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE someval="UpdatedValue" ;
```

As this record already exists , i need to update the row or else create a new record based .

Comment: The table has to have a unique index so it knows which columns to check for duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare the primary key of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video_video_sprout` (
  `video_id` int(6) default NULL,
  `sprout_video_id` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `is_video_type` tinyint(1) default NULL ,
  `someval` varchar(25) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (video_id, sprout_video_id)
) ;
```

Without a unique key, `INSERT` can't detect a duplicate key.

Comment: I cannot have a primary key on video_id as it will have two rows of video_id ,

Comment: that is the problem right there... on duplicate key won't work without an unique constraint

Comment: Then your database schema is broken. And you still need a unique id or something else unique for the match to match on.

Comment: I can have a composite primary key on video_id and  sprout_video_id